# Pass select option value to input field using VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to grab the value from a select option and pass it to the input field name so I can create different input fields on button click.

So far I have an array of input fields but I'm not sure how to grab the select option value and output this within the input name field, resetting it each button click.

**Markup**

```
  <div id="app">

    <ul>
      <li v-for="(input, index) in inputs">
        <input type="text" v-model="input.one">
        <button @click="deleteRow(index)">Delete</button>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <select v-model="inputType">
      <option selected="selected">Select a field to add</option>
      <option value="text">Text</option>
      <option value="file">File</option>
      <option value="email">email</option>
    </select>
    <button @click="addRow">Add row</button>

  </div>
```

**VueJS**

```
const app = new Vue({

  el: '#app',

  data: {
    inputs: []
  },

  methods: {
    addRow() {
      this.inputs.push({
        one: ''
      })
    },
    deleteRow(index) {
      this.inputs.splice(index,1)
    }
  }

})
```

JSFiddle - 
https://jsfiddle.net/u2r1fpu4/

Comment: Can you reproduce your attempt in a fiddle?

Comment: Updating sorry missed that bit

Comment: You can `watch` for changes to `inputType` and react to that. That's how you grab what's been selected. On click, simply do the action (add an input) and then set the `inputType` to `null`. Also, define it in your `data()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have binded the value of the select input to inputType, just use the inputType variable.

```
  <div id="app">

<ul>
  <li v-for="(input, index) in inputs">
    <input v-bind:type="input.type">
    <button @click="deleteRow(index)">Delete</button>
  </li>
</ul>

<select v-model="inputType">
  <option selected="selected">Select a field to add</option>
  <option value="text">Text</option>
  <option value="file">File</option>
  <option value="email">email</option>
</select>
<button @click="addRow">Add row</button>
```

```
const app = new Vue({

  el: '#app',

  data: 
  {
    inputs: [],
  },

  methods: {
    addRow() {
      this.inputs.push({
        type: this.inputType
      })
    },
    deleteRow(index) {
      this.inputs.splice(index,1)
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Aha correct, but that binds the option value to the input value instead of the name attribute of the field.

Comment: I wish to bind the option value ```inputType``` to the name attribute of an input html tag e.g ```<input type="inputType" />``` I under stand I probably need a ```v-bind:name``` here.

Comment: I have edited my answer with what I believe is correct, I've tried it and it's working, the added input will be of the type selected. 
You bind the type of the input (v-bind:type).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, so I'm just taking a guess here

```js
const app = new Vue({
  
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    inputs: [],
    selection: ""
  },
  
  methods: {
    addRow(selection) {
      this.inputs.push({
        type:selection, 
        one: ''
      })
    },
    deleteRow(index) {
      this.inputs.splice(index,1)
    }
  }
  
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="app">
    
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(input, index) in inputs">
        <input v-if="input.type === 'text'" type="text" v-model="input.one">
        <input v-else-if="input.type === 'file'" type="file" v-model="input.one">
        <input v-else-if="input.type === 'email'" type="email" v-model="input.one">
        <button @click="deleteRow(index)">Delete</button>
        {{input.type}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    <select v-model="selection">
      <option value="" >Select a field to add</option>
      <option value="text">Text</option>
      <option value="file">File</option>
      <option value="email">email</option>
    </select>
    <button @click="addRow(selection)">Add row</button>
    
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

note that you can't do `<input :type="input.type" v-model="input.one">` and would need to have a set of `v-if/v-else-if` instead